# IPython Notebook with Spark on EC2 : Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipython, pyspark

I am trying to run the simple WordCount job in IPython notebook with Spark connected to an AWS EC2 cluster. The program works perfectly when I use Spark in the local standalone mode but throws the problem when I try to connect it to the EC2 cluster.

I have taken the following steps

I have followed instructions given in this [Supergloo blogpost](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-cluster-amazon-ec2-tutorial/).

No errors are found until the last line where I try to write the output to a file. [The lazyloading feature of Spark means that this when the program really starts to execute]

This is where I get the error

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]16/08/05 15:18:03 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Actually there is no error, we have this warning and the program goes into an indefinite wait state. Nothing happens until I kill the IPython notebook.

I have seen this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469462/taskschedulerimpl-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources) and have reduced the number of cores to 1 and memory to 512 by using this options after the main command

```
--total-executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 512m
```

The screen capture from the SparkUI is as follows
[sparkUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITKD.png)

This clearly shows that both core and UI is not being fully utilized.

Finally, I see from this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176197/with-spark-how-to-connect-master-or-solve-an-errorwarn-taskschedulerimpl-init) that

> The spark-ec2 script configure the Spark Cluster in EC2 as standalone,
>   which mean it can not work with remote submits. I've been struggled
>   with this same error you described for days before figure out it's not
>   supported. The message error is unfortunately incorrect.
>
> So you have to copy your stuff and log into the master to execute your
>   spark task.

If this is indeed the case, then there is nothing more to be done, but since this statement was made in 2014, I am hoping that in the last 2 years the script has been rectified or there is a workaround. If there is any workaround, I would be grateful if someone can point it out to me please.

Thank you for your reading till this point and for any suggestions offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can not submit jobs except on the Master - as you see - unless you set up a REST based Spark job server.